# Chrome doesn't show any site properly (artifacts)

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, kde4

Whenever I minimize, and maximize then my Chrome browser it starts to show artifact on any site that "move the half of the site in the transverse". It dissapear when any of site element change their look and show again when i scroll the website using any method. funny thing is that screenshot doesn't catch it
[image]